# Rails throwing error: Association named 'media' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to find all users that have made a comment under the same picture.

In psql terminal I write this and it gets me all the info I need:

```
    select * from users
inner join comments on users.id = comments.user_id
inner join media on media.id = comments.media_id
where media_id = 1
```

Now in Rails I am currently doing this:

```
@users = User.joins(:comments, :media).where(media_id = @medium.id)
```

Which should work I think.
But when trying to print out all the user names from `@users` in my view, this error is thrown:

```
Association named 'media' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Have I done my join clause wrong here?

DB Schema:

```
create_table "media", force: true do |t|
    # Unrelevant columns
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "media", ["user_id"], name: "index_media_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    # Unrelevant columns
    t.integer  "user_id",                 null: false
    t.integer  "media_id",                null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["media_id"], name: "index_posts_on_media_id", using: :btree
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                   default: "", null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `media` is associated directly with `comments` instead of `users`, you should have:

```
@users = User.joins(comments: :media).where(comments: {media_id: @medium.id})
```

Comment: It will produce this SQL: `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."user_id" = "users"."id" 
INNER JOIN "media" ON "media"."id" = "comments"."media_id" WHERE (1)` The bad part here is that in the first `INNER JOIN`, it does `ON comments.user_id` not `users.id`

Comment: Error that it thrown `PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: ...IN "media" ON "media"."id" = "comments"."media_id" WHERE (1)`

Comment: @Kaspar please show me relevant part of your db schema.

Comment: @Kaspar I edited my answer. You had an error in `where` clause.

Comment: the `where` clause is now adding "users" in front of media.id for some reason. `WHERE "users"."media_id" = 1`. This will also throw an error.

Comment: @Kaspar right, I forgot `media_id` is in `comments` table. Check it now.